# jQuery Uncheck checkbox not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

After trying multiple examples on StackOverflow to fix my issue, I still can't figure out my problem.

I have 3 checkboxes:

```
<input id="pets_dog" class="text" type="checkbox" class="pets" name="pets[]" value="pets_dog"> Dogs</input>
<input id="pets_cats" class="text" type="checkbox" class="pets" name="pets[]" value="pets_cats"> Cats</input>
<input id="pets_none" class="text" type="checkbox" class="pets" name="pets[]" value="pets_no"> None</input>
```

And when "pets_none" is checked, I need the other 2 checkboxes to be unchecked and vice versa. Here is my current jQuery code:

```
        $("#pets_none").change(function() {
            if($("#pets_none").attr('checked')) {
            $("#pets_cats").removeAttr('checked');
            $("#pets_dogs").removeAttr('checked');
            } 
        });
```

I can't figure out for the life of me why it's not working, and appreciate any help.

Comment: You should not have 2 class attributes assigned as that is invalid Html. Having 2 class attributes also prevents you for example from selecting your inputs by class of `pets`. I.e: `$(.pets)` won't work as `.text` takes precedence. If you want 2 classes assigned do it like this `class="text pets"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your html should be

```
<input id="pets_dog" class="text pets" type="checkbox" name="pets[]" value="pets_dog" /> Dogs
<input id="pets_cats" class="text pets" type="checkbox" name="pets[]" value="pets_cats" /> Cats
<input id="pets_none" class="text pets" type="checkbox" name="pets[]" value="pets_no" /> None​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
   $("#pets_none").on('change', function(e) {
       if($(this).is(':checked')) {
           $("#pets_dog").attr('checked', false);
           $("#pets_cats").attr('checked', false);
       } 
   });
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/u6wVG/)

**Update :**
You have used class attribute twice, it should be as follows

```
<input id="pets_dog" type="checkbox" class="pets text" name="pets[]" value="pets_dog" /> Dogs
<input id="pets_cats" type="checkbox" class="pets text" name="pets[]" value="pets_cats" /> Cats
<input id="pets_none" type="checkbox" class="text pets" name="pets[]" value="pets_no" /> None​
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    $(".pets").on('change', function(e) {
        var el=$(this);
        if(el.is(':checked') && el.attr('id')=='pets_none') {
            $(".pets").not(el).attr('checked', false);
        }
        else if(el.is(':checked') && el.attr('id')!='pets_none')
        {
            $("#pets_none").attr('checked', false);
        }  
    });
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/u6wVG/4/)

Comment: @FrançoisWahl I did not bother to include the "else" block considering if I could get the first block to work, than editing "else" wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @SheikhHeera Thank you very much for the update. This is exactly what I needed and allowed me to cut off 8 lines of code. I greatly appreciate the DEMO link.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `prop` method:

```
 $("#pets_none").change(function() {
     if (this.checked) {
        $("#pets_cats, #pets_dog").prop('checked', false);
     } 
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `.prop()` method:

```
...

$("#pets_cats").prop('checked', false);
$("#pets_dogs").prop('checked', false);

...
```

And to check whether the `#pets_none` is checked, use that method too:

```
$("#pets_none").prop('checked');
```

Comment: I've tried that and still to no avail. At this point I'm thinking that another function may be messing up this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

```
var checked = $(this).find('Enable').text().toLowerCase();
$("#chk__Enable").each(function () {
    if (checked == 'true') {
        $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
    } else {
        $(this).removeAttr('checked');
    }
});
```

Comment: I know prop is the way to go with newer version of jQuery. however this answer worked for me when prop did not (specifically for IE9). using attr / removeAttr works for both IE9 and IE10 renderings of my app.